# Is it possible to override a superclass' method with a parameter extending the superclass' method parameter?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract

Say I have a class like so:

```
abstract class Something {}
```

And it has a hierachy with classes extending it:

```
class FirstSomething extends Something {}
class SecondSomething extends Something {}
```

Then elsewhere I have a class making use of these somethings:

```
abstract class A {
    public void setSomething(Something something) {
        //Process the something
    }
}
```

Am I able to specify a subclass of A, so that it overrides the setSomething method, with the more specific "something" classes?
This is what I want to be able to do:

```
class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void setSomething(FirstSomething something) {
        //Process the something
    }

class C extends A {
    @Override
    public void setSomething(SecondSomething something) {
        //Set the something
    }
```

At the moment I am doing something like this in the A class:

```
public void setSomething(Something something) {
    checkClass(something);
    //Use the something
}
protected abstract void checkClass(Something something);
```

where the B class and C class throw an exception in the checkClass method if the type of the SuperSomething is not the right one for those classes.

EDIT:
I have tried with the exact method signatures as above, but the subclass methods do not override the super's method, I suppose I am really asking:
Is there a way to specify a method in the super class' definition, where there is a compile-time check for the types of object allowable in the setSomething method for subclasses of the superclass?

Comment: Did you try compiling it to see if it's allowed?

Comment: I've tried and it doesn't override the super's method, I'll rephrase the question

Comment: What is `SuperSomething`?

Comment: A mistake, changed it now!

Comment: The overriding is fine. There is something else wrong with the method implementation. Where does it throw exception in class `B` and `C`? And where is the implementation of `checkClass` method?

Comment: @RohitJain The overriding is not fine. It's not the same type parameter in B and C as in A. It's an overload.

Comment: I was trying to convey that there is an abstract method "checkClass" in the "A" class, so classes B and C must implement this checkClass method, they check the type of the Something, and throw an exception if the type is the wrong type, however Alexis posted a solution to the question

Comment: @AlexisC. Damn, I've started to forget these concepts.. :(

Comment: @RohitJain You may have mixed up with the return type, that can be a subtype (covariance). :-)

Comment: @AlexisC. Yeah, exactly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make the A class generic by specifying that the type can be `Something` or one of its subclasses (I've made the `setSomething` method abstract but you can provide an implementation if you want).

```
abstract class A <T extends Something> {
    public abstract void setSomething(T something);
}
```

Then force the type T to be the specific class you want in your subclasses.

```
class B extends A<FirstSomething> {
    @Override
    public void setSomething(FirstSomething something) {
        //Set the something
    }
}

class C extends A<SecondSomething> {
    @Override
    public void setSomething(SecondSomething something) {
        //Set the something
    }
}
```